# unrecognized selector "length" when attempting to log entire managed object with overridden getter/setter

Tags: ios, core-data, key-value-coding

I use core data to store some arrays as strings. The strings are prefixed with STRINGFROMARRAY and delimited by &,&.

I thought it would be neat to override the setters and getters so I wouldn't have to provide code to convert them every time I needed access. I have created a managed object subclass called TestEntity with only one attribute, "memberIds" (string). I have verified that my custom setter and getter seem to work fine:

TestEntity.h:

```
@interface TestEntity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (NSArray*)memberIds;
- (void)setMemberIds:(NSArray *)memberIds;

@end
```

TestEntity.m:

```
@implementation TestEntity

@dynamic memberIds;

- (NSArray *)memberIds
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"memberIds"];
    NSArray *memberIdsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"memberIds"] substringFromIndex:15] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&,&"]];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"memberIds"];
    return memberIdsArray;
}

- (void)setMemberIds:(NSArray *)memberIds
{
    NSString *stringFromArray = [@"STRINGFROMARRAY" stringByAppendingString:[memberIds componentsJoinedByString:@"&,&"]];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"memberIds"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:stringFromArray forKey:@"memberIds"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"memberIds"];
}

@end
```

I can set an array value and it properly stores as a string. I can also use `valueForKey` to log the value after it's set, and it properly prints as an array.

**However**, when I attempt to log the *entire* managed object (without valueForKey:), I get a [NSArray length] unrecognized selector error.

Here's the code I'm using to test this:

```
NSManagedObject *test = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TestEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[SyncEngine sharedEngine].managedObjectContext];
[test setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil] forKey:@"memberIds"];
NSLog(@"%@", [test valueForKey:@"memberIds"]);
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

And here's the output:

```
2013-08-24 13:59:27.820 0.1[1440:19d03] (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
2013-08-24 13:59:27.820 0.1[1440:19d03] -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa533800
```

Why is the `length` message getting sent to my array? And how can I prevent this crash? Thanks!

Comment: Does the stack trace in the debugger point to anything helpful?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think so, but I'm inexperienced with using stack traces. The debug navigator (with max frames displayed) shows 4 entries (after the button to execute the test code is pressed) in the stack trace: 3 _ CF_forwarding_prep_0; 2 _ forwarding_; 1 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]; 0 objc_exception_throw.

Comment: Why not just save the array as transformable?

Comment: @Wain Hm, I'm not sure; I read that transformable is not searchable, but of course neither is my string (practically speaking) without special handling. With my custom setter/getter, I can presently execute fetch requests like this: `NSManagedObject *fetchResult = [[SyncEngine sharedEngine] fetchClassNamed:@"TestEntity" withPredicates:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memberIds contains 1"]][0];` and that works perfectly. That's a nice feature. Would I be able to accomplish the same and with fewer problems by switching to transformable? I'm not sure about all the pros and cons. Thanks

Comment: No, you wouldn't. Go with @Gougou and use different methods to avoid conflicts with the model introspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have overriden memberIds methods.

In your model, memberIds should return a string, and you've overriden it to return an NSArray.
So, when your managedobjet is trying to generate its description, it is assuming that memberIds is a string.

I think the best way to do that it to name your custom getter / setter differently than your model attribute.

Comment: Thanks. This may be the solution. I'd still be able to do a predicate search on the array, e.g, `NSManagedObject *fetchResult = [[SyncEngine sharedEngine] fetchClassNamed:@"TestEntity" withPredicates:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memberIdsArray contains 1"]][0];`. But I'm going to wait a bit and see if anyone comes along who knows how to make it work with overwriting the default setter/getter because I am interested in having a better understanding of what goes on behind the scenes when a manangedObject "generates its description" and if there's anything crafty I can do to influence that.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to ask: in what other situations besides `NSLog` would this configuration cause an error?

Comment: I think the problem isn't with NSLog, but with the implementation of the -(NSString *)description of NSManagedObject.

In fact, 
    `NSLog(@"%@", anObject); `
Is the same as 
    `NSLog(@"%@", [anObject description]); `

So the problem will occur each time so will call description on your NSManagedObject.